# Moderncv - Centering name and informations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, moderncv

I'm using `moderncv` to write my CV but right now, the name is in the top-left of the page, and the information (Age, address, email etc...) in the top-right.

Is that possible to align name and information in the top-middle of the page ? I'd like something like this:

> - Full name
> - Adress
> - Phone number
> - email

(Centred).

If you could explain me how to do it (I don't know how to use '\renewcommand').

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The predefined `banking` style in `moderncv` does this. Just put `\moderncvstyle{banking}` in your preamble. Of course, there's then the question of whether or not you like the way that the `banking` style typesets the main content of your cv...

Comment: Hi, thanks you, this is what I was looking for !

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, `moderncv` currently has 5 default themes (`casual`, `classic`, `banking`, `oldstyle`, and `fancy`).

Of these 5 default themes, `banking` is the only one that puts the title/header information in the top center of the page, like you want:

[image]

To use this theme, you just need to declare `\moderncvstyle{banking}` in your preamble.

The following MWE produces the document in the screen shot above:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

While it is possible to customize `moderncv`, if you're not satisfied with `banking`, it might ultimately be easier to build your own template.